# python change a string to list , string contains brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3, I have this below list

["Device","kdi","fdf,"False"]

How can i turn this string to list. So i can read values of 0 as device. value OF 1 as kdi, and so on. Currently when am trying to read, the value of 0 am getting is [ than value of 1 is " than value of 2 is d....

Comment: Would you mind including a bit more detail around the task at hand? Some code?

Comment: sounds like an XY-problem... How do you get this string from the first place?

Comment: @Tomerikoo It's hardly an XY problem - it's a normal and sensible enough problem that the standard library function `json.loads` does it. (That's also why it's an obvious duplicate.)

Comment: @kaya3 maybe I misuse the term XY, what I meant is if OP provide more context to the problem it might be solved in a different more easy way from the start

Comment: The string probably comes from a file or a network request.

Comment: @kaya3 not always a safe assumption, I'm afraid. Often, people are dumping the string representation of some list object to a text file and calling that serialization. In which case, `json.loads` won't work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In that case, the other standard library function `ast.literal_eval` also works. The fact that there are two options built in rather underscores the fact that it's a usual and reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = '["Device","kdi","fdf","False"]'
>>> l = literal_eval(s)
>>> print(l[0])
Device
```

Comment: Hi this works, with only an issue. If it is ["Device","kdi","fdf",False]

Comment: last element boolean crashes it.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` works just fine with booleans. The problem is you missed a closing " quote character on the third element.

Comment: hi its not closing, it is crashing . But i think it has to do with false, being small letter.

Comment: Then your string is probably in json format and you should use json.loads. You should correct your original question then.